# How to deal with proxy setting in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

I am learning to create my own web browser for iPhone. I use `UIWebView`, and using [this article](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/), I can create it easily.

But the problem arises when I had to do it behind a proxy server. I set up Squid in Mac OS X using [this article](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=816), and having set Mac OS X network preferences to use this new proxy, my application won't work anymore. I try the Safari inside iPhone Simulator, and it will display login for the username and password of the proxy.

How can I do it inside my own UIWebView?
At first task, maybe it's adequate to hardcode it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the first time I answered my own question.
It solved rather easily : use this library : [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). So I change my code from this :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[addressBar text]];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[addressBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Into this :

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString: [urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] retain];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setUsername:@""];
[request setPassword:@""];

[request startSynchronous];
```

It will prompt for username & password if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance of this working w/o ASIHTTPRequest. I have a proxy only at work.

Comment: @tudorizer Well, no idea about that anyway :)