# load pages in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to display web pages using UIwebview on iPad.

I used following code :-

```
   NSString *urlAddress=@"http://google.com";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
   NSLog(@"The value of url in screen 2 is %@",url);
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [web loadRequest:requestObj];
```

web is an object of type uiwebview .
This works fine with certain links but when i tried to open below link 
http://deverpids.ltisap.com:8000/sap(bD1lbiZjPTgwMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/zbbdashboard/demo.htm#infohttp://deverpids.ltisap.com:8000/sap(bD1lbiZjPTgwMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/zbbdashboard/demo.htm#info
It does not display anything .Read few articles and taught this could be related to a proxy issue

[How to deal with proxy setting in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885169/how-to-deal-with-proxy-setting-in-uiwebview)
so tried to use this but no success . code used is as below :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"error is %@",response);
    }
```

But now nothing loads up in webview .how do i tackle this .

Comment: if I click on the link my browser tells me that the site does not exist. Maybe the same happens thing happens in your app?

Comment: I can confirm the above behavior with the link, it is invalid.

Comment: i dont think so ..because it works with one of the code snippets and not with other ...help me out on what could be the issue .