# How to load public url to proxy network on WebView iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

How to load a public url like www.google.com on proxy network with using Credential,
for accessing the public url from proxy network for ios sdk application.

I am try

But's its loading empty blank page on webivew!

Answer (score 0):

use this library : [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Now do this to create request:

```
  NSString *strUrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
  NSURL *urlAddress = [NSURL URLWithString: [strUrlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  ASIHTTPRequest *proxyrequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:strUrlAddress];

 [proxyrequest setUsername:@""];
 [proxyrequest setPassword:@""];

 [proxyrequest startSynchronous];

  NSError *error = [proxyrequest error];
  if (!error) {
   NSString *response = [proxyrequest responseString];
   NSLog(@"Response : %@",response);
  }
   NSLog(@"\nError: %@",[error description]);
```

Credit goes to [@swdev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885169/how-to-deal-with-proxy-setting-in-uiwebview) for his answer

It will prompt for username & password if needed.

Comment: why  ASIHTTPRequest need if its not https. url!